# How to export database from mysql console

Tags: mysql, database, shell, ssh

I´ve try export a database but I can´t.

This command is correct?

```
(drupaluser@localhost) [(none)]> mysqldump cw-db-arka > cw-backupDB.sql
```

what is: [(none)] ?

Comment: lookup the mysqldump command. if you have access rights it will be something like mysqldump -uuserName -ppassword database > fileNameToHoldDump

Comment: "what is [(none)]?" is it a real question and what do you need to know? in general your command is fine unless you do not need to provide user/password and the rest options like --single-transaction

Answer (score 0):

In your command you've only specified the name of the database (cw-db-arka) and the name of the output file (cw-backupDB.sql). You also need to give `[mysqldump][1]` your username and password:

```
mysqldump -u username -p cw-db-arka > cw-backupDB.sql
```

Obviously, `username` should be substituted with whatever your username is. The `-p` option will prompt you for your password.